# lyx bibliography citation style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, lyx, citing

I create a `.bib` file

```
@article {HanKumar2011,
author = {Han, Bing and Kumar, Alok},
title = {Speculative Retail Trading and Asset Prices},
journal = {Journal of Financial and Quantitative Analysis (JFQA)},
volume = {Forthcoming},
year = {2011},
}
```

I then import this file into by `.lyx` file by doing `insert > list/toc > bibtex bibliography`. I select the database as the file I have created. The style I select as `plainnat`.  I then go to cite the paper via `insert > citation`, add the particular id, the preview of the actual cite seems to show up fine.  However the problem is that the only citation style available is `[#ID]` under formatting.  I need one that allows me to do `author (yyyy)`.  I can't seem to fix this. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems you have to activate this in the settings, so go to Document --> Settings --> Bibliography, and choose Natbib and author-year as citation style. Then you'll have more styles to choose from.

[image]

Comment: Is there an example list of styles available, so I can predict what will be generated?

Comment: Note -- it doesn't seem sufficient to change the citation style of your master document. I had to also change it for each child document before the natbib options appeared in the citation dialogue.

Comment: I have changed this in my document and changed each citation style to (Surname, year). The LyX preview shows the citation style I want. However, the resulting PDF remains in the numeric [1] style. (LyX 2.1 on Windows)

Comment: @badp Which bibliography style are you using? Works fine here with `plainnat`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ooooh, good catch! You also have to set your bibliography section to use `plainnat` instead of `plain`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I make the exact same manipulation but it gives me the following error message "Paragraph ended before \org@@citex was complete". What can I do ?

Comment: @optimalcontrol I have no idea, ask a new question that includes a minimal example (see https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample), and maybe someone can figure it out.